# Pointers to functions of similar layout allowed in an union?

Tags: c, struct, function-pointers, unions

The following code compiles and runs fine with gcc. But i wondered if such an union is define by the standard and if it works on all c compilers the same way. I know it will not work if, parameters of that functions are not pointers and not compatible with each other, but as long as all paramters are pointers and the number of parameters are the same there shouldn't be a problem, or?

```
typedef struct node {
    unsigned long int key;
} node_t;

typedef struct node1 {
    unsigned long int key;
    char *str;
} node1_t;

typedef struct node2 {
    unsigned long int key;
    void *data;
} node2_t;

typedef struct node3 {
    unsigned long int key;
    int numbers[256];
} node3_t;


int compare(node_t *a, node_t *b) {

    printf("%ld ? %ld\n", c->key, d->key);
    return c->key == d->key;
}

struct comp {
    union {
        int (*c0) (node_t  *a, node_t  *b);
        int (*c1) (node1_t *a, node1_t *b);
        int (*c2) (node1_t *a, node2_t *b);
        int (*c3) (node1_t *a, node3_t *b);
        int (*c4) (node2_t *a, node1_t *b);
        int (*c5) (node2_t *a, node2_t *b);
        int (*c6) (node2_t *a, node3_t *b);
        int (*c7) (node3_t *a, node1_t *b);
        int (*c8) (node3_t *a, node2_t *b);
        int (*c9) (node3_t *a, node3_t *b);
    } are;
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    node1_t a[] = {
        { 23477843258923UL, "Hello World" },
        { 10254892378892UL, "Hello Back" }
    };
    node2_t b[] = {
        { 83296783479803UL, NULL },
        { 52348237489832UL, (void *) &a[1] }
    };
    node3_t c[] = {
        { 91308823949203UL, { 3, 4, 5 } },
        { 17587832478823UL, {43, 43, 43, 86 } }
    };

    struct comp comp;
    comp.are.c0 = compare;

    comp.are.c1(&a[0], &a[1]);
    comp.are.c2(&a[1], &b[0]);
    comp.are.c3(&a[0], &c[1]);
    comp.are.c8(&c[1], &b[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `union` is valid, but what you are doing with it is not.  You cannot put something into the `union` with one type and then use it with another like the end of `main` is doing unless those types are convertible (thanks to @Christoph for that comment).

Comment: C99-TC3 explicitly allows this - see section 6.5.2.3, footnote 82: If the member used to access the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last used to store a value in the object, the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is reinterpreted as an object representation in the new type as described in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called "type punning"). This might be a trap representation.

Comment: ...however, the code still involves undefined behaviour as it calls a function through a pointer of incompatible type...

Comment: @Christoph: I corrected it and cited you in there; see if you like the new version better.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of whether it's valid, it's hideously ugly. C has `void *` for a reason.

Here's how to use it:

```
int compare(void *a, void *b) {
    node_t *c = a, *d = b;
    printf("%ld ? %ld\n", c->key, d->key);
    return c->key == d->key;
}
```

Comment: You are right. Is there a not ugly way to get a warning/error at compile time if a function doesn't support certain parameter types/combinations?

Answer (score 0):

As Jeremiah said, getting data out of a union through a different member than you used to put the data in is technically undefined behavior (but it's probably the closest you will ever get to standardized undefined behavior). That being said, why not move the union to the place you really want it? What you want is a way to call a function that takes 2 nodes that may have different types of data. So instead of making a union of function pointers that take 2 nodes of differing data, move the union to where the differing data actually is: make a function that takes 2 nodes that hold a union of differing data, that is, move the union into the `Node` class so a single `Node` type can hold the various types of data (AKA `str`/`data`/`numbers`) (although you might want to change the `int[256]` to an `int*` in that case).

Just be aware that whether or not this will work will be *highly* dependent on the platform you compile for (specifically the calling convention).

Comment: Yes to put the union in the Node would definitely make sense in that example. What i want is a way to define which parameter types and combinations are allowed for a specific function and have that checked at compile time not runtime. But I might forget this way.